# " TypeError: _internal_init() got multiple values for argument" error when created Azure App Insights with Pulumi

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights, pulumi

I wanna create Azure Application Insights with Python with this [reference](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/insights/component/#inputs).

And also this [reference](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/tree/master/sdk/python/pulumi_azure_native/insights/v20200202preview) is about the update of SDK.

I imported a special version with:

```
from pulumi_azure_native.insights import v20200202preview as insights
```

My code is:

```
app_insights = insights.Component('app_insights',
                                      args=insights.ComponentArgs(
                                          application_type='web',
                                          kind='web',
                                          flow_type='Bluefield',
                                          ingestion_mode='LogAnalytics',
                                          resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
                                          location=location_name,
                                          resource_name=get_resource_name(
                                              'app-insight'),
                                          tags=tags_group,
                                          workspace_resource_id='/subscriptions/****-***-**-ae8b-****/resourcegroups/rg-dev-gx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/insight-wkspc-gx',
    
                                      ),
                                      )
```

with this code I received the error:

```
__self__._internal_init(resource_name, opts, **resource_args.__dict__)
TypeError: _internal_init() got multiple values for argument 'resource_name'
error: an unhandled error occurred: Program exited with non-zero exit code: 1
```

Comment: As per multiple GitHub issues, `insights.Component` documentation is yet to be updated for latest API version `v20200202` . You can refer to https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/1392  and https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/1525

Comment: @MadhurajVadde-MT Thanks for your comment. I updated my question. As for your links, I imported `v20200202` and also used `workspace_resource_id` but I received the same error. I receive the same error. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: please open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need, give a try using the classic library `Azure Classic` for Pulumi.

```
import pulumi
import pulumi_azure as azure


my_resource_group = azure.core.ResourceGroup("my_resource_group", location="West Europe")
my_analytics_workspace = azure.operationalinsights.AnalyticsWorkspace("my_analytics_workspace",
                                                                           location=my_resource_group.location,
                                                                           resource_group_name=my_resource_group.name,
                                                                           sku="PerGB2018",
                                                                           retention_in_days=30)
my_insights = azure.appinsights.Insights("my_insights",
                                              location=my_resource_group.location,
                                              resource_group_name=my_resource_group.name,
                                              workspace_id=my_analytics_workspace.id,
                                              application_type="web")
pulumi.export("instrumentationKey", my_insights.instrumentation_key)
pulumi.export("appId", my_insights.app_id)
```

This is for python but in the link below you can also see for TypeScript for example.
https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure/api-docs/appinsights/insights/